# cant we append a nsmutable string to another nsmutablestring

Tags: objective-c, append, nsmutablestring

```
NSMutableString *mSt1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] stringWithString:asong.at];
            NSMutableString *mSt = [[NSMutableString alloc] stringWithString:[mSt1 substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (0, 2)]];
            NSMutableString *mSt2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] stringWithString:[mSt1 substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (5, 2)]];
            NSMutableString *str = [mSt appendString:mSt2];
            [songsHrs addObject:str];
            [mSt release];
            [mSt1 release];
            [mSt2 release];
```

getting the error at line no.4  error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

help me out please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[mSt appendString:mSt2];
```

This method has a return type of `void`.  It modifies the `NSMutableString` you call it on (`mSt` in this case), but returns nothing.

So don't expect a return value.  Delete the `NSMutableString *str` and just use it directly.

```
[songHrs addObject:mSt];
```

Since the string is mutable, it simply changes itself in place.  No need to save the result in a separate variable.  In fact, this is the entire point of using `NSMutableString` instead of `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Squeegy already wrote about appending, your lines 1, 2 and 3 seem also broken - you should call initWithString and not stringWithString, or use stringWithString but no alloc. The whole construct is messy though and doesn't really make sense - but this is for testing purpose probably.